# Android support v7 MediaRouter sometimes doesn't work properly

Tags: android, audio, bluetooth

I use v7 support library MediaRouter for switching routes between phone's speaker and bluetooth device.

And sometimes it works strange, for example, when I turn off the bluetooth, corresponding route seems to be removed (playback switches to the speaker), but my application doesn't receive any callback about it. And moreover, when I manually get all the routes via MediaRouter.getRoutes(), it returns that bluetooth route, but when I try to switch to it, it seems to be selected, but actually playback still goes through the speaker.

I tried all the flags CALLBACK_FLAG_FORCE_DISCOVERY, CALLBACK_FLAG_REQUEST_DISCOVERY etc, without result. Only phone reboot helps. Any suggestions?

I used Android 4.2, 4.4.

UPDATE, code sample:
....

```
private MediaRouter mMediaRouter;

    private MediaRouter.Callback mMediaRouterCallback = new MediaRouter.Callback(){
        @Override
        public void onRouteAdded(MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.RouteInfo route) {
            super.onRouteAdded(router, route);
            refreshRoutes();
            Log.i(TAG, "Route added ==> " + route.getName());
        }

        @Override
        public void onRouteRemoved(MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.RouteInfo route) {
            super.onRouteRemoved(router, route);
            refreshRoutes();
            Log.i(TAG, "Route removed ==> " + route.getName());
        }

        @Override
        public void onRouteSelected(MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.RouteInfo route) {
            super.onRouteSelected(router, route);
            Log.i(TAG, "Route selected ==> " + route.getName());
            refreshRoutes();
        }

        @Override
        public void onRouteUnselected(MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.RouteInfo route) {
            super.onRouteUnselected(router, route);
            Log.i(TAG, "Route UNselected ==> " + route.getName());
            refreshRoutes();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mRoutesList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.routesList);

        mRoutesList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                String routeName = mRoutesAdapter.getItem(i);

                List<MediaRouter.RouteInfo> routes = mMediaRouter.getRoutes();
                for (MediaRouter.RouteInfo rout : routes){
                    if (rout.getName().equals(routeName)){
                        mMediaRouter.selectRoute(rout);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        mMediaRouter = MediaRouter.getInstance(this);
        mMediaRouter.addCallback(
                new MediaRouteSelector.Builder()
                        .addControlCategory(MediaControlIntent.CATEGORY_LIVE_AUDIO)
                        .addControlCategory(MediaControlIntent.CATEGORY_REMOTE_PLAYBACK)
                        .build(),
                mMediaRouterCallback,
                MediaRouter.CALLBACK_FLAG_REQUEST_DISCOVERY);

        mRoutesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 0);
        mRoutesList.setAdapter(mRoutesAdapter);

        refreshUi();
    }

@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        mMediaRouter.removeCallback(mMediaRouterCallback);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

private void refreshRoutes(){
        mRoutesAdapter.clear();
        MediaRouter.RouteInfo selectedRoute = mMediaRouter.getSelectedRoute();
        List<MediaRouter.RouteInfo> routes = mMediaRouter.getRoutes();
        for (MediaRouter.RouteInfo rout : routes){
            if (rout == selectedRoute)
                mRoutesAdapter.add(rout.getName() + " [selected]");
            else
                mRoutesAdapter.add(rout.getName());
        }
        mRoutesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: Can we see some code please.

Comment: @Iocrizak So you are doing all the work concerning the MediaRouter in an `Activity`? Do it in a foreground `Service` instead and I am guessing all your problems will disappear...

Comment: The end goal of the app I am making is there are speakers in 4 corners of a booth, which has been simplified to 2 speakers with a left and right channel. A sound plays and the user has to select with speaker or speaker channel the sound played out of. The activity is handling the randomization of which speaker to play the sound out of. How would I do this same functionality in a Service? I'm very new to Android (popping my app cherry on this!) and I haven't used Services yet.

Comment: Yes, just read up on it and it sounds exactly what I need.

Comment: As far as i know, MediaRouter is only responsible for finding all the available media routes in your phone. Detecting wether it is active or not is someone else's job. You've explained the entire problem but i think that there's still a question in the air: what do you want to accomplish? Receiving bluetooth state change broadcasts? I still don't get it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using @Xaver's suggestion in the question comments, I put all of the MediaRouting in a Service. I got everything working how it was before the service but the same error was occurring. When I returned to an activity, after one switch from the wired to the BlueTooth speaker, the `MediaRouter` would get stuck on the wired speaker despite saying that the current route was the Bluetooth speaker.

Switching from `android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter` to the `android.media.MediaRouter` and refactoring my code a little everything worked perfectly. Hard to say if moving the routing to a service was part of the combination but I got it working (after ~50 hours of tinkering with everything)

The unfortunate thing with `android.media.MediaRouter` is it doesn't have a `getRoutes` method, but nothing a little Googleing couldn't handle! Since I found it a pain to figure this out from the docs, since everything is referencing the `v7` library, below is how to get the MediaRouter and select a route.

```
MediaRouter mr = (MediaRouter)this.getSystemService(this.MEDIA_ROUTER_SERVICE);
mr.selectRoute(mr.ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO, mr.getRouteAt(0));
```

Hopefully this helps someone!

Comment: Able to share complete working code? I am using the v7 version and the MediaCallbacks are not called when a Route is added or removed (those events show up in logs though) and so I can't track availability of route reliably.

Comment: @AndrewMackenzie sorry I don't have access to that code anymore